# How to make vertical menu that is split in 2 auto width columns using CSS grid?

Tags: html, css

I have menu with a number of elements that I don't know:

```
<ul>
  <li>Link with long text 1</li>
  <li>Link 2</li>
  <li>Link 3</li>
  <li>Link 4</li>
  <li>Link 5</li>
  <li>Link 6</li>
  <li>Link 7</li>
</ul>
```

I'm trying to split it in 2 columns with auto width and equal amount of elements in each:

[image]

The following CSS does the job but it requires me to manually specify amount of rows.

```
ul {
  display: grid;
  gap: 10px 40px;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 1fr);
}
```

Is there any way to 'tell' CSS "rows should be half of element count"? Or maybe there are better ways to solve this?

Comment: Please don't report the same question again. the linked duplicate to your original question already states that this is not possible. You will have to rethink your approach.

Comment: The original post was closed with a link to other CSS columns post. So I assumed that whoever closed it didn't read to the CSS grid part. So this time I asked about CSS grid. Please stop closing questions that have people trying to answer them.

Comment: Your still trying to solve the same problem....and there is no CSS method to do this. You need JS or an different approach.

Answer (score -1):

With some help from JS i think this would work for you

```
<style>

ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    gap: 10px;
    height: 300px;
}

</style>

<ul class="ul-element">
    <li>Link with long text 1</li>
    <li>Link 2</li>
    <li>Link 3</li>
    <li>Link 4</li>
    <li>Link 5</li>
    <li>Link 6</li>
</ul>

<script>

const ul = document.querySelector(".ul-element");
const li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
const amount = li.length;
const row = Math.ceil(amount / 2);
const height = 100 / row;

for(element of ul.getElementsByTagName("li")){
    element.style = 'height: calc(' + height + '% - 10px);';
}

</script>
```

Comment: This results in left to right, top to bottom. I need links to go top to bottom, left to right.

Comment: help me understand, you want them to fill the first column then go to the next column?

Comment: Yes. I want half of them to fill first column and half the second column.

Comment: `flex-direction: column;` might work for that. [flex-guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: i dont think there is a way to do that using purely css